# Issues running jquery slider and lightbox on same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Complete noobie trying to teach myself some javascript.

Basically, I can't get a lightbox to run at the bottom of my page while running a slider towards the top.  I started with the slider and it works perfectly on it's own.  However, when I add the code to run the lightbox, it doesn't work and the slider stops working.  I believe my issue is with my CSS, but I'm not sure.  Any help is appreciated.

In the head:

```
<!--Main Page Stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="CSS/inland-wood.css" />

<!-- Slider -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
<link href="CSS/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript">  // This is the script for the banner slider
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').s3Slider({
            timeOut: 3000
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Lightbox Effect -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<link href="CSS/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript">  // This is the script for the lightbox effect
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#thumbnails a').lightBox();
        });
    });
</script>
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="thumbnails">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <a href="images/photos/01-turntable-illustration-graphic.png"  title="Turntable">
        <img src="images/photos/01-turntable-illustration-graphic-thumbnail.png" alt="turntable">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="images/photos/02-robot-diy-kit.png" title="DIY Robot Kit">
        <img src="images/photos/02-robot-diy-kit-thumbnail.png" alt="DIY Robot Kit">
      </a>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

My CSS:

```
/** reset lightbox position **/
#lightbox-container-image-data-box {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/** page structure **/
#w {
    display: block;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 30px;
}

#content {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
    -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 0px 1px 2px 0px;
}

#thumbnails {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#thumbnails ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 26px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code after the last script in your header:

```
<script>
    $.noConflict();
<script>
```

Here is your revised code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="CSS/inland-wood.css" />

<!-- Slider -->
<link href="CSS/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  // This is the script for the banner slider
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slider').s3Slider({
            timeOut: 3000
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- Lightbox Effect -->
<link href="CSS/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  // This is the script for the lightbox effect
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#thumbnails a').lightBox();
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $.noConflict();
<script>
```

NOTE: this isn't related to your problem but, you should always add the CSS link *before* the Script it pertains to.

Comment: Yep... that worked.  I really appreciate the response.  If you have the time, do you care to give a quick explanation as to why the conflict was created.  I would've thought that because both scripts were running off the same locally hosted jquery file, that it would've just ran the scripts in order sequentially.  Either way, thanks again for the help!

Comment: It's hard to tell without reading through and examining both scripts. All I can tell you is that the `noConflict()` function is there for this type of scenario. Sorry that I can't give you anymore details about the conflict between your scripts though.